# How to configure a docker container as a systemd service?

Tags: linux, docker

I've used the following service definition file to set up a systemd service.

```
[Unit]
Description=MappingService
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=3000
WorkingDirectory=/home/oren/MappingService
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/sudo /home/oren/MappingService/deploy.sh /home/oren/MappingService/eb-mapping-service.tgz
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /home/oren/MappingService/ebms_run.sh
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That service's purpose is to launch a specific docker container. The operation appears to be successful as the docker appears in:

```
docker container ls
```

it is listening on port 9090 and I succeeded in verifying that port is open with nmap.

but when I check the service status on systemctl, (`systemctl status mappingservice.service`)
I get inactive(dead) as appears below.

> ● mappingservice.service - MappingService    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/systemd/system/mappingservice.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: **inactive (dead)** since Thu 2019-02-14 14:54:20 IST;
>   20min ago   Process: 1784 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo
>   /home/oren/MappingService/ebms_run.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
>   Process: 1323 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sudo
>   /home/oren/MappingService/deploy.sh
>   /home/oren/MappingService/eb-mapping-service.tgz (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)

I've searched on here for clues and I only found references to systemd usage of the actual docker service and not a specific container like I'm trying to do here.

Contents of ebms_run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source defs.sh

DOCKER_PARAMS="-v /dev/log:/dev/log -d --log-driver=journald --add-host=<server1-alias1>:172.17.0.1 --add-host=<server1-alias2>:172.17.0.1 --network=bridge -p 9090:9090 --name ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME}"


docker rm -f ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME}
docker run ${DOCKER_PARAMS} ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME} /bin/bash -c "cd /build/MappingService; ./start_multiple_clients_mapping_service.sh
```

The script `start_multiple_clients_mapping_service.sh` is running inside the docker container and is actually continuous. It will not die until the docker dies.

**Question:**
**How should I configure my systemd service to manage the docker container?**

Comment: What seems to happen is that your script finishes executing straight away. You have to show us what's in ebms_run.sh.

Comment: @StefanR I've added reference to ebms_run.sh script's content.